# Querying using DynamoDB vs AWS Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I am creating an iOS app that will query my database without doing any object manipulation or calculation, I can do this in several ways:

1. Query directly using DynamoDB iOS SDK
2. Query using AWS Lambda iOS SDK, and then executing a lambda function that queries DynamoDB directly.

My question is, which is more execution-time and cost efficient?

My thoughts are that option 1 is the best as it does not require a function or any execution time.

I know that I am charged for the DynamoDB query and I know that I am charged for the execution time of the lambda function. However, I am not sure if I will be charged for using the DynamoDB SDK method or for something else or if I might forgetting another possible cost or thing that I am not taking into account.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Using DynamoDB is cheaper, but it has serious (in my opinion) drawbacks:
- Security. You need to figure out how to manage users of your app accessing your DynamoDB, likely by using Cognito.
- Complexity. This has to do with security. You have to come up with security policies which can be hard.
- Vendor lock-in. You are tying your app to the DynamoDB proprietary SDK. If tomorrow you decide to switch to a SQL database or some other NoSQL service you will have a hard time.
Using lambda with API gateway as a Middleware to DynamoDB overcomes most of the issues and enables you to use your own authorization mechanism (not necessarily AWS policies).

Answer (score 0):

Your thought is correct, executing the query using DynamoDB IOS SDK is better for execution time and cost.

Additionally you will be charged for [data transfer](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-data-transfer-price-reduction/) (for both approaches).

However its not advisable to store the Access Keys & Secrets inside IOS app, where you need to consider using [temporary security credentials](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_temp.html) possibly with [AWS Cognito](https://aws.amazon.com/cognito/).

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB has a issue with Security - Dynamo DB does not have a VPC endpoint yet. Hence its better to go for redis elastic cache if you have VPC endpoint restrictions.

VPC - Virtual private cloud